# copyFromLocal: `/user/hduser/gutenberg': No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I have followed the guide of michael-noll so far but got stuck here.

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

13/11/11 23:24:13 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
copyFromLocal: `/user/hduser/gutenberg': No such file or directory

hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$
```

I have tried reformatting the name node with 'Y' but getting same result every time for any arbitrary folder name.

Any ideas?

Comment: Solved it by using 

hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/hduser  

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 27):

Solved it by using the command like:

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/hduser
```

Answer (score 2):

### Hadoop 2.4.1

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hduser/sample
```

Answer (score 2):

For Hadoop 2.6.0 :

Usage: hadoop fs -mkdir paths

Example:
   **hadoop/bin** fs -mkdir /user/hduser

Ref: http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-commandline-manage-files-hdfs/